# Отобразить изображение из массива пикселей по нажатию кнопки MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

Недавно начал изучать MFC и при написании программы наткнулся на такую проблему. При нажатии на кнопку открывается диалоговое окно с открытием файла (*.dcm формата), из файла я достаю массив пикселей, который необходимо преобразовать в hbitmap и вывести в PictureControl. 
Т.е. открываю файл и изображение отображается в PictureBox. 
Как можно преобразовать в hbitmap?

Пример моего кода(как я пытаюсь это сделать)

```
    image->setMinMaxWindow();
        Uint8 *pixelData = (Uint8 *)(image->getOutputData(8));
        if (pixelData != NULL){
            int w = image->getWidth();
            int h = image->getHeight();

            int* tt = new int[5000000];

            for(int i = 0; i<w; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j<h; j++) {
                    tt[j+i*w] = pixelData[j+i*w];
                }                       
            }   

            /*BITMAPFILEHEADER* bmfh; 
            bmfh = (BITMAPFILEHEADER*)tt; 

            BITMAPINFOHEADER* bmih; 
            bmih = (BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(tt + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)); 
            BITMAPINFO* bmi; 
            bmi = (BITMAPINFO*)bmih; 

            void* bits; 
            bits = (void*)(tt + bmfh->bfOffBits); 

            HDC hdc = ::GetDC(NULL); 
            HBITMAP hbmp = CreateDIBitmap(hdc, bmih, CBM_INIT, bits, bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

            m_picture.ModifyStyle(0xF, SS_BITMAP, SWP_NOSIZE);
            m_picture.SetBitmap(hbmp);
*/
            BITMAPINFOHEADER bmih;
            bmih.biSize     = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
            bmih.biWidth    = 1000;
            bmih.biHeight   = -1000;
            bmih.biPlanes   = 1;
            bmih.biBitCount = 8;
            bmih.biCompression  = BI_RGB ;
            bmih.biSizeImage    = 0;
            bmih.biXPelsPerMeter    =   10;
            bmih.biYPelsPerMeter    =   10;
            bmih.biClrUsed    =0;
            bmih.biClrImportant =0;

            BITMAPINFO dbmi;
            ZeroMemory(&dbmi, sizeof(dbmi)); 
            dbmi.bmiHeader = bmih;
            dbmi.bmiColors->rgbBlue = 0;
            dbmi.bmiColors->rgbGreen = 0;
            dbmi.bmiColors->rgbRed = 0;
            dbmi.bmiColors->rgbReserved = 0;
            void* bits = (void*)&(pixelData[0]); 

            HDC localDC = ::GetDC(NULL);
            // Create DIB
            HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(localDC, &dbmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &bits, NULL, 0);

            if (hBitmap == NULL) {
                AfxMessageBox("Error",IDOK);
                return;
            }else m_picture.SetBitmap(hBitmap);

            delete tt;
```

Выводит чёрный экран.

Comment: а зачем вы начали изучать MFC? Это технологий очень старая. Это не в упрек, а ради того, чтобы вы понимали, что вы изучаете.

Comment: В данный момент необходим MFC. Дальше будем больше изучать.

Comment: тогда улучшите запрос, приведите пример кода, который у вас не работает